# Regex match all strings except one with a certain word

Tags: regex

I'm using this for iOS shortcuts, not sure what language that is.

I have text like this

```
Begin (random characters) a word (random characters) End
```

This is repeated multiple times.

`Begin` and `End` are always the start and finish of the string.

I'm wanting to match every Begin to End group of text that doesn't contain "a word" that I know.

Example:

```
Begin dghugcdfhnbcd foo sdfyhnvdsd End
Begin sdhhnvdsgg bar drykjbcds
End
```

Match the one that doesn't have `foo`.

I thought this was working but got feedback that it was not.

```
Begin((?!foo).)*End
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The reason, your regex doesn't work is that the last 'End' is on a new line (. does not match a newline). You can use this instead: Begin((?!foo)[\s\S])*?End